# How can I hide my API key from other contributors on my GitHub repo (Nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, api, github, next.js, axios

Is it possible to hide the API key while at the same time allowing other contributors to use it while in development?

I'm using Nextjs

Comment: Sure, there are lots of ways to do secrets management. Or you could have developers generate their own individual secrets.

Comment: Did you know ENV?

Answer (score 0):

We can hide our api_key inside `.env` file.

inside `.env`

```
USER_ID=239482`
```

getting api key insde other file

```
process.env.USER_ID; //239482
```

you can also read form here
https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs/

Comment: But then I'd have to include the .env file in the repo, otherwise how would a contributor be able to use it if they don't have the .env file on their local machine?

Comment: you can add the .env file in gitignor and add your variables in git deployment variables. so your keys won't be available on the code.